# Determine if site resides in a sub folder in php

Tags: php, url

I have a strange issue to solve. Lets say I have a vps, and in it i set up my site rum from `example.com/site` - you can clearly see that `site` is a sub folder and visiting it causes the url to look like `http://example.com/site`. Now lets say that I configure apache such that the url looks like: `http://example.com` but in fact the true url is still `http://example.com/site`.

I want to write a php function that states:

*if `site` is a sub folder do this, else do that that*

That would need to check if I am looking at `example.com/site` (regardless of apache configurations) or if I am truly looking at `example.com`

thoughts?

Comment: Look for something in the `$_SERVER` array (eg `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) that you can apply string/pattern matching to.

Comment: Do you have any example, I figured it would use $_SERVER

Comment: if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'site')) { echo 'yep, it's /site'; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this..

```
    $urie = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : '';

        //experimental echo to see with what we are dealing with
        echo $urie;

            if($urie == '/site')
            {
            //do this, or..
            // $urie = str_replace('/site', '', $urie);
            }
            else
            {
            //do that
            }
```

If you want to search for a "/site" from a complex url (like "example.com/site/image/3333.jpg"), I think you could use `preg_match` I suppose, or even `replace` if you need to maneuver to different folder, or you have maybe "base ref" problem.

Depending on your need for this tweak, answer/solution may be different.